# Android felix development

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix

i have working on how to re-form my developed android app to adopt the Felix framework. i have followed the steps on : http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html. However, they said "Apache Felix can also be integrated with an Android application. To achieve this, you need to embed Felix into onCreate() method of your Activity class (see Android docs for more details on how to use an Activity) and process your bundles as shown above." I do not understand what it exactly means. Does any body know how to develop a app based on Felix framework?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Felix on Android, but what this means is that you bootstrap the framework manually in the onCreate() method. The following code is an example of starting a framework and installing some bundles.

```
 FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader
        .load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
    Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
    framework.start();

    BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
    List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<>();
    bundles.add(
        context.installBundle("file:org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.10.0.jar"));
    bundles.add(
        context.installBundle("file:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.10.0.jar"));
    bundles.add(
        context.installBundle("file:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar"));

    for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
        bundle.start();
    }
```

Comment: thk, i will try soon :)